# MongoDB geolocation, origin of two circles within each other (or not)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB database with records that have `location` (which is `[longitude,latitude]`) and `radius` (which is *miles*).  In my NodeJS side of things, I have a `user` variable that has `latitude`, `longitude`, and `searchRadius` (also *miles*) as properties.

I'm able to easily find whether or not a db record's origin is within the user's "circle" with this query:

`{ location: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ user.longitude, user.latitude ], user.searchRadius ] } } }`.

However, what I *also* need is to see if the user's origin is within the db records "circle".  Basically, I need to see if both *origins* fall within each other's "circles".  How might I go about this with one query?

If it helps a solution, I do have a 2dsphere index on `location` in the db.

For some context, the records in the database are places that only want to work within a given radius around them, which is why it needs to line up in both directions; as the user would only want to travel so far on their side, too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with spheres, use [$geoNear](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#geonear-aggregation) instead of $geoWithin

```
{$geoNear: {
    spherical: true,
    maxDistance: user.searchRadius,
    near: {type:"point", coordinates:[user.longitude, user.latitude]},
    distanceField:"calcDist"
}}
```

This will find all documents that are within the search radius, but also calculate the distance and include that in the document.  Follow that with a match stage to select documents where distance is less than the radius:

```
{$match: {$expr:{$lte:["$calcDist","$radius"]}}}
```

Also note that the radius in [centerSphere](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/#-centersphere) should be in radians, not miles.